# how to only install security/critical updates on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, updates

I recently updated windows 10 using windows update after a fresh OS install and noticed it reinstalled a lot of the bloatware I removed beforehand and installed new useless software, changed my privacy and device settings, re-enabled many services that I had manually disabled. So I was wondering if there was a way to only install security/critical updates on windows 10 and not have the update also change my settings and configurations.

Comment: Feature updates are required if you are running Windows 10 Home or Professional.  You can only defer updates on Windows 10 Professional for a period of time eventually they will be installed.  Feature updates can be defended for 4 months and quality updates can be deferred for a small amount of time.

Comment: I think Microsoft missed the boat on this one. As an end-user (Home or Professional), I still want control over what applications get installed on my computer. I **hate** that Microsoft auto-installs anything except for critical updates. There is **no** explanation from them that will convince me that they have any right to load my computer up with applications that I have to just uninstall, with all the clutter that is left behind anytime you uninstall anything on Windows. Windows 10 perpetuates a poor application model from earlier Windows OS's and now adds new irritations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Windows 10 Professional, Enterprise, or Education,

- Go to **Settings**.
- Click **Windows Update**.
- Scroll Down and click on **Advanced options**.
- Tick the checkbox that says **Defer Updates**.

This prevents Windows from downloading feature updates and only critical security updates are installed.

You won't have a problem with Windows reinstalling bloatware and changing your security settings once you install the Creator's update as Windows will respect your choices.

Comment: "Defer Updates" --> This option delays feature upgrades for several months while allowing security updates through. This means that after a certain time, windows will still install all the other feature upgrates

Comment: @ViktorCarlson Yes, true. Do you feel I should have highlighted how one can block Windows Updates using a firewall?

Comment: If deferring means the bloatware will be installed later and critical updates will be installed now, then marking `defer updates` isn't the answer to the OP's question.  I too want to stop Windows Update permanently from installing anything except for critical updates.  How is that done?

Comment: and yet again windows 1809 does the same, enables disabled services, task schedules, installs the default uwp bloatware apps from ms, installs onedrive again for the thousandth time.. so people. look out. this answer is outdated and incorrect.